# Suppose $X$ is a complete metric space. Is the complement of a countable union of nowhere-dense sets a dense set?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

I am able to prove this if we have a countable collection $\{E_n\}$ of *closed* nowhere-dense subsets, however I am being asked to prove it for a countable collection of nowhere-dense sets that *need not* be closed. I haven't been able to come up with a way to show it. Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what are you talking about? if you take the closures of the $E_n$'s, you get a bigger union and the union consists of closed nowhere-dense sets. so you know the complement is then dense. and this complement is smaller than the complement of the original union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all $E_n$ are closed and nowhere dense, $\bigcup_n E_n$ is of first category and so its complement is $\bigcap_n E_n^{\complement}$, which is the intersection of countably many open and dense subspaces, so dense by Baire's theorem.

If the $E_n$ are just nowhere dense, then by definition $F_n = \overline{E_n}$ is closed and nowhere dense and

$$(\bigcup_n E_n)^{\complement} \supseteq (\bigcup_n F_n)^{\complement} = \bigcap_n F_n^{\complement}$$ and the right hand side is already dense by the closed case hence so is the larger set $(\bigcup_n E_n)^{\complement}$ too.

Comment: My guess (based upon the title of the question) is that the OP meant countable unions only. The “arbitrary” is because this is about arbitrary sets, not just closed ones.

Comment: Yes, I mean to say countable unions of arbitrary sets, that need not be closed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos If we have arbitrary nowhere dense sets it's true a fortiori, as their closures are even bigger and they already have a dense complement for their union...

Comment: Ok, so you've shown that the complement of the union of the sets $E_n$ contains a dense set, so is therefore dense itself. Thank you for the answer!